# Retrieving Runtime Changed ThemeData Problem

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

My story in short is, I can successfully change app theme dynamically, but I fail when it comes to start my app with the last chosen `ThemeData`.

Here is the main.dart:

```
import "./helpers/constants/themeConstant.dart" as themeProfile;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    //Several ChangeNotifierProviders
  ],
  child: Consumer<AuthenticateProvider>(
    builder: (ctx, authData, _) => ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
      create: (_) {
        ThemeData themeToBeSet;

        themeProfile.setInitialTheme().then((themeData) {
          themeToBeSet = themeData;
        });

        return ThemeChanger(themeToBeSet);
      },
      child: _MaterialAppWithTheme(authData),
    )
  )
);}}
```

The problem is `themeToBeSet` variable always being null eventhough I set a ThemeData as I do below:

```
ThemeData selectedTheme;

Future<ThemeData> setInitialTheme() async {
 final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

 if (!preferences.containsKey(ApplicationConstant.sharedTheme)) {
  selectedTheme = appThemeDataDark;

  final currentThemeInfo = json.encode({
  "themeStyle": ApplicationConstant.darkAppTheme
 });

 preferences.setString(ApplicationConstant.sharedTheme, currentThemeInfo);

 return selectedTheme;
}
else {
 final extractedThemeInfo = json.decode(preferences.getString(ApplicationConstant.sharedTheme)) as 
 Map<String, dynamic>;

 final chosenTheme = extractedThemeInfo["themeStyle"];

 if (chosenTheme == ApplicationConstant.lightAppTheme) {
  selectedTheme = appThemeDataLight;

  return selectedTheme;
 }
 else if (chosenTheme == ApplicationConstant.darkAppTheme) {
  selectedTheme = appThemeDataDark;

  return selectedTheme;
 }
 else {
  selectedTheme = appThemeDataDark;

  return selectedTheme;
}}}
```

Here, I used `shared_preferences.dart` package to store and retrieve ThemeData info. If I debug this block, I see that my `selectedTheme` variable is set one of these ThemeData successfully. But, for a reason I couldn't able to find out, `themeToBeSet` variable on `main.dart` is not assigned to the result of my `setInitialTheme()` method.

Is it because of being asynchronous? But, isn't Dart waiting an asynchronous method with `.then()`?

In order not to leave any questionmarks realated for my other sections, I'm also sharing ThemeChanger class,

```
class ThemeChanger with ChangeNotifier {
 ThemeData _themeData;

 ThemeChanger(
  this._themeData
 );

 getTheme() => _themeData;

 setTheme(ThemeData theme) {
  _themeData = theme;

 notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

And, _MaterialAppWithTheme,

```
class _MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthenticateProvider authData;

  _MaterialAppWithTheme(
    this.authData,
  );

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Game Shop Demo',
      theme: theme.getTheme(),
      home: authData.isLogedin ?
      HomeScreen(authData.userId) :
      FutureBuilder(
        future: authData.autoLogin(),
        builder: (ctx, authResult) => authResult.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ?
        SplashScreen():
        LoginScreen()
      ),
      routes: {
        //Several named routes
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, I misused `.then()`.

I thought Dart is awaiting when you use `.then()` but after running into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937162/how-to-use-futures-inside-changenotifier/56938403#56938403), I learnt that it is not awaiting..

So, I carry `setInitialTheme()` method to `ThemeChanger` class (it was in a different class previously) and call it in the constructor. Here its final version,

```
class ThemeChanger with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;

  ThemeChanger() {
    _setInitialTheme();
  }

  getTheme() => _themeData;

  setTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    _themeData = theme;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<ThemeData> _setInitialTheme() async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (!preferences.containsKey(ApplicationConstant.sharedTheme)) {
      _themeData = appThemeDataDark;

      final currentThemeInfo = json.encode({
        "themeStyle": ApplicationConstant.darkAppTheme
      });

      preferences.setString(ApplicationConstant.sharedTheme, currentThemeInfo);

      return _themeData;
    }
    else {
      final extractedThemeInfo = json.decode(preferences.getString(ApplicationConstant.sharedTheme)) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final chosenTheme = extractedThemeInfo["themeStyle"];

      if (chosenTheme == ApplicationConstant.lightAppTheme) {
        _themeData = appThemeDataLight;

        return _themeData;
      }
      else if (chosenTheme == ApplicationConstant.darkAppTheme) {
        _themeData = appThemeDataDark;

        return _themeData;
      }
      else {
        _themeData = appThemeDataDark; //Its better to define a third theme style, something like appThemeDefault, but in order not to spend more time on dummy stuff, I skip that part

        return _themeData;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, as you can see, ThemeChanger class is no longer expecting a ThemeData manually, but setting it automatically whenever its called as `setInitialTheme()` method is assigned to its constructor. And, of course, `MyApp` in `main.dart` is changed accordingly:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
       //Several ChangeNotifierProviders
      ],
      child: Consumer<AuthenticateProvider>(
        builder: (ctx, authData, _) => ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
          create: (_) => ThemeChanger(),
          child: _MaterialAppWithTheme(authData),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Now, app is launching just fine with the last selected `ThemeData` which has a pointer stored in `SharedPreferences`.